# How can I make a Classroom's Post (only with Material) on API call?

Tags: google-classroom

My question here is about Google Classroom's API.

When i am in the Classwork tab, I have a button to make posts; one option is "material". This type is not an assignement and does not have an assigned grade. This is a perfect concept: I can add materials, sorted by topics to my classwork page with no grades or assignments needed.

The problem for me is when i go to the api and look for that functionality, you can only see `courseWork` objects with `"ASSIGNMENT" "SHORT_ANSWER_QUESTION" and "MULTIPLE_CHOICE_QUESTION"` workTypes.   All of those type have grades related, but no option exists for the "MATERIAL" type I can choose from the Create menu.

Nor do Material objects seem to exist in the API call.

Many other objects exist that I can find:  coursework, announcements, topics, students, courses, teachers and others, but no material's object. Is this an omission?  There is a "material" available but it's used for the attachments IN a CourseWork item, not the CourseWork itself.

Answer (score 1):

Jose- I think I asked the same question as you but might have been clearer with the details.  Perhaps check here if answers start to roll in.  I have spent hours trying to interrogate objects to find this info with no luck.

[Google Classroom API Create Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528327/google-classroom-api-create-material)

I would have added this as a comment but my reputation doesn't allow it.

UPDATE:  Huge thanks to @ziganotschka for this:

> Indeed, there is a feature request for it already:
>
> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127591179
>
> I suggest you to give it a star to increase visibility and get updates
>   on the implementation status of the feature.